# Is it possible to reuse scalar result from a single subquery in insert query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I would like to insert several rows of data in Postgres DB table in the same query, but value for one of the columns needs to be calculated using a scalar result from a sub-query and a passed bound parameter. The calculation is a concatenation of two Postgres arrays.

I was able to do it with a query like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, computed_col)
VALUES 
  (
    :col1Val1,
    :col2val1,
    (SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id = :id) || ARRAY[:computed_col1]::bigint[]
  ),
  (
    :col1Val2,
    :col2val2,
    (SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id = :id) || ARRAY[:computed_col2]::bigint[]
  );
```

CTE works as well, but it looks unnecessary due to the fact that we still need **SELECT** subquery from CTE "table" for each set of values.

As you can see **SELECT** subquery is the same for each set of data to be inserted. So is it possible somehow to specify single subquery and reuse the result without repeating **SELECT** sub-queries, or maybe there is some other way(s) to optimize the query above?

And what issues the query can cause from a performance point of view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do use `insert . . . select`, basically moving the `VALUES()` into the `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, computed_col)
    SELECT v.col1, v.col2, x.some_col  || v.computed
    FROM (SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id = :id
         ) x CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (:col1Val1, :col2val1, ARRAY[:computed_col1]::bigint[]),
                 (:col1Val2, :col2val2, ARRAY[:computed_col2]::bigint[])
         ) v(col1, col2, computed);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do you think what query will be more performant (of course if it is possible without explain/analyse tools)?

Comment: @dajnz . . . Performance should be pretty irrelevant for adding two rows.  If `some_table` has an index on `id` (which is presumably the primary key), then I would be surprised if you could measure the difference in performance.